# What is "branch-on-sign expressions"?

Tags: language-agnostic

As far as I understand the "branch-on-sign" is the name of some kind of `if` statement that does something depending on sign.  I'm not sure that it's just `if (x<0) then ... else ...`.

However, the name  "branch-on-sign" seems to denote something very concrete.  So, what is it?  Perhaps, it's language-specific, but I don't really know.  Probably, it's related to embedded development.

Comment: Where did you see that phrase?

Comment: @Michael, in a description of a DSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In assembler, it is an instruction which branches (jumps) if the result of the last arithmetic operation had a specific sign. So,

```
ADD A, B
JMI FOOBAR
```

would jump to location FOOBAR if the result of adding A and B was negative, for some hypothetical architecture.